# android volatile variable in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

i have

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private volatile boolean wifiNetwork = false;
private volatile boolean mobileNetwork = false;

}
```

and i am cheking boolean variable all the time receiver is executed. Is it smart to use `volatile` variable here or not? I don't have any thread but i always want the latest state of this variable.

Comment: Broadcast events are [delivered synchronously](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive) unless explicitly specified. So, this is not needed mostly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volatile will keep your value up-to-date only for multiple threads. If you use a single thread then you should not concern about that. But you should consider keeping your values in user preferences, because if instance of class is destroyed (very likely) then you will get new values (default ones).

Comment: so you suggest keeping this variables in user preferences. Is instance of class destroy often? For example BroadcastReceiver instance?

Comment: I think there is no need to keep these values in a data store. Wifi/Mobile network state can be changed before relaunching the app.

Comment: In this particular case you can check network availability right inside onReceive() method. But, in general, keeping values in user preferences is necessary. Very likely, system kills broadcast receiver instance right after onReceiver() is finished.

Answer (score 3):

There is no sense in making variable volatile if only one thread is using the object.